# How do I get multiple inputs from UI?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code so far

```
def sbc(): #splits up dataframe by account
    accounts = []
    acc = raw_input("Enter account abbreviations one at a time. Enter 'end' to load media lists.")
    frame = rlf()
    while True:
        if acc == 'end':
            break
        else:
            accounts.append(acc)
        for ac in accounts:
            frame = frame[frame['Campaign'].str.startswith(ac)]
            path = r'C:\\Users\\CP\\Documents\\Python_WL\\'+str(ac)+str(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))+'.xls'
            if len(frame) > 50:
                frame.to_excel(path)
```

I want to be able to have multiple entries in 'account', however, when I run the program it only allows me to input one value. I doubly confused because another portion of code does repeat in the way I want it to for 'account' that code being:

```
def rlf(): #removes low fill rate
    frame = rbs()
    inputted_fill_rate = raw_input("Fill Rate cutoff? (Format: 0.nn): ")
    return frame[frame['Fill Rate'] >= float(inputted_fill_rate)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `raw_input` call to inside the loop. You probably also want to de-indent the `for` loop.

```
def sbc(): #splits up dataframe by spotx account
    accounts = []
    frame = rlf()
    while True:
        acc = raw_input("Enter account abbreviations one at a time. Enter 'end' to load media lists.")
        if acc == 'end':
            break
        else:
            accounts.append(acc)
    for ac in accounts:
        frame = frame[frame['Campaign'].str.startswith(ac)]
        path = r'C:\\Users\\CP\\Documents\\Python_WL\\'+str(ac)+str(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))+'.xls'
        if len(frame) > 50:
            frame.to_excel(path)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks, I will watch my indenting next time